# CloudFormation tags for instances created by LaunchConfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How can I add a Name tag to instances created by CloudFormation's LaunchConfig? I thought it would be in this section, but it is not an option.

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
   "Properties" : {
      "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : Boolean,
      "BlockDeviceMappings" : [ BlockDeviceMapping, ... ],
      "ClassicLinkVPCId" : String,
      "ClassicLinkVPCSecurityGroups" : [ String, ... ],
      "EbsOptimized" : Boolean,
      "IamInstanceProfile" : String,
      "ImageId" : String,
      "InstanceId" : String,
      "InstanceMonitoring" : Boolean,
      "InstanceType" : String,
      "KernelId" : String,
      "KeyName" : String,
      "PlacementTenancy" : String,
      "RamDiskId" : String,
      "SecurityGroups" : [ SecurityGroup, ... ],
      "SpotPrice" : String,
      "UserData" : String
   }
}
```

I wondered if I should create an instance resource and put settings in there, and then link it to the launchconfig, but I can't find any documentation to support that idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) is meant to be used in conjunction with  [AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html). The AutoScalingGroup itself has a [Tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-tags) property that can be used for setting the instance name among other tags. One note about these tags, they're slightly different than the tags used in most other CloudFormation resources, as they have a `PropagateAtLaunch` property, which says if the tag should be applied to instances of the AutoScalingGroup, or just the AutoScalingGroup itself. See the [Auto Scaling Tags Property Type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-tags.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, this works! I did try this, but hadn't realised that PropagateAtLaunch was required in the tags field, so it failed. More here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-tags.html#cfn-as-tags-PropagateAtLaunch

Comment: but how to tag BlockDevices? only via `aws-cli` in user-data?